# Angular material sidenav inbox like

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

For my tool (which I developed entirely with angular material)  I wanna construct a page with a layout like [inbox.google.com](http://inbox.google.com)

Here is my problem. The sidenav provided in angular-material is full height and cover the main toolbar. Here is an [example](http://codepen.io/ThomasBurleson/pen/LEZvWw)

```
 <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')">
```

How can I imitate that behaviour with md-sidenav?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways we can do this.

You should give this css and js library a go.

http://materializecss.com/

Its similar to bootstrap but its designed in material and has a vast amount of javascript functionality and animations.

See here as well for working specifically wth angular-material to achieve this http://brilliantbritz.com/2015/06/17/creating-your-own-angular-material-right-navigation-menu/. This guide will explain it better than I ever could.

Comment: Hi Jonjoe. Thank you. I will consider this framework too. I have chosen angular-material (and have developed most part of my site with that) because it simplify the intermediation with angular. Do you know a method for doing that with angular-material?

Comment: Ahh cool, 

You may want to make that a tad clearer as i overlooked it. Sorry!

I will update my answer.